# CGRectFromString() for general structs

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
@"{0, 1.0, 0, 1.0}"
```

I wish to convert the above string to a struct like this:

```
struct MyVector4 {
    CGFloat one;
    CGFloat two;
    CGFloat three;
    CGFloat four;
};
typedef struct MyVector4 MyVector4;
```

`CGRectFromString()` does the same thing, only for `CGRect`. How can I do it for my own structs?

Comment: You write a function that parses the string and fills in the struct.

Comment: Is that how CGRectFromString() does it? I assumed there was a more convenient way using eval or equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a function for rect it means that it is not working by default.

You have to create your own function something like MyVector4FromString.

You may like to to know that you can init struct object like this also.

```
MyVector4 v1 = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4};
```

This is a very easy C syntax. so I don't think you require to init from string.
See here : [4.7 — Structs](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/47-structs/)

But if you are getting string from server or from other function than yes you have to create your function to do this. You can parse string and init 4 float value.

This link will help you to divide string in multiple part : [Split a String into an Array](http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/Strings/split.html)

All the best.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in  the following way:

```
 -(MyVector4)myVector4FromString:(NSString*)string
    {
        NSString *str = nil;
        str = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, string.length - 1)];
        NSArray *strs = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

        MyVector4 myVec4 = {0,0,0,0};
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
            CGFloat value = ((NSString*)[strs objectAtIndex:i]).floatValue;

            if (i==0) { myVec4.one = value; } else
            if (i==1) { myVec4.two = value; } else
            if (i==2) { myVec4.three = value; } else 
            if (i==3) { myVec4.four = value; }
        }

        return myVec4;
    }
```

This function can parse strings in format shown in your question like `@"{12.0,24.034,0.98,100}"`

Comment: Very Nice. I would like to replace two line for making substring with one :  str = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, string.length - 1)];. Replace in your original code if you think it suit in your code.